# Find update query execution count for last 24 hours in mongo db collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Find update query execution count for last 24 hours in mongo db collections
how to fire up query to find out how many times update query has been executed last 24 hours on the mongodb collections?

Comment: What you are looking for can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/  .

Answer (score 1):

The response from the serverStatus command include [opcounters.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/index.html#serverstatus.opcounters.update), which is:

> The total number of update operations received since the mongod instance last started.

If you query that periodically, you can calculate how many updates operations occurred during each period.